# i want to keep show social icon with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

i have js script for button when i click it show social icon and  when i click back its hide. but i want to keep show all social icons. below is my js scipt.`// Bind the social button to show/hide the social icons box

```
        $('#social-pop-out-trigger').click(function() {
        var $allBoxes = $('.footer-pop-out-box');
        if ($allBoxes.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        var $thisBox = $('.social-pop-out-box');
        if ($thisBox.is(':visible')) {
            $thisBox.slideUp();
        } else {
            if ($allBoxes.is(':visible')) {
                $allBoxes.filter(':visible').slideUp(function() {
                    $thisBox.slideDown();
                });
            } else {
                $thisBox.slideDown();
            }
        }

        return false;
    });
```

```js
$('#social-pop-out-trigger').click(function() {
   var $allBoxes = $('.footer-pop-out-box');
   if ($allBoxes.is(':animated')) {
    return false;
   }

   var $thisBox = $('.social-pop-out-box');
   if ($thisBox.is(':visible')) {
    $thisBox.slideUp();
   } else {
    if ($allBoxes.is(':visible')) {
     $allBoxes.filter(':visible').slideUp(function() {
      $thisBox.slideDown();
     });
    } else {
     $thisBox.slideDown();
    }
   }

   return false;
  });
```

```
        $('#social-pop-out-trigger').click(function() {
        var $allBoxes = $('.footer-pop-out-box');
        if ($allBoxes.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        var $thisBox = $('.social-pop-out-box');
        if ($thisBox.is(':visible')) {
            $thisBox.slideUp();
        } else {
            if ($allBoxes.is(':visible')) {
                $allBoxes.filter(':visible').slideUp(function() {
                    $thisBox.slideDown();
                });
            } else {
                $thisBox.slideDown();
            }
        }

        return false;
    });`
```

Comment: can your put your code in JSFiddle and share?

Answer (score 0):

Hope your social icons are hidden using CSS or Javascript.

You have to find where it is hidden and make it visible.

Otherwise, try commenting all those function and just have

```
$('.social-pop-out-box').show();
```